# kafka Rest calls + D3 animated chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, apache-kafka

I am building a dashboard that renders events as D3 charts.
For example, a D3 bubble chart; where bubble sizes are revised based on events consumed from a kafka topic over the rest api. I have similar code to do this for a database datasource (using async xsjs calls); iterating on SELECT statements to refresh the data; but I'm unclear if I can use the same technique for kafka rest calls.

I'd like to have all of the javascript code embedded in a HTML page (for simplicity) but I suspect that calling a kafka rest service cannot be done using browser js code as I cannot find examples of this on github.

How best to consume output from kafka rest calls in javascript?

Comment: Do you mean the Kafka REST proxy? Natively, Kafka does not communicate over REST... By the way, what you're asking for has mostly been done here https://www.arcadiadata.com/product/streaming-visualizations/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use REST calls to consume from Kafka, using the open source [Kafka REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest).